# Printing list of captured objects in Python

Tags: python

How would you go about getting the list of dependencies injected into a method, but are unseen?

Pointing to some reading would also be great :)

Example:

```
external_object = "abc"
def func(data, params) 
    print(external_object)
    ...

def get_list_of_dependencies(func):
   # TODO
```

The get list of dependencies would print out the external object. The reason I am trying to do this is because I am trying to memoize the function func, but because of these external dependencies injected into the function, a hash that I created does not fully work.

Thank you!

Comment: This is probably my own lack of understanding, but what does it mean to memoize a function? And what are external injected dependencies? Are there outside libraries?

Comment: Also, you have a *function* not a method.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Still in the context switching phase in my head :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want can be achieved by inspecting the `__code__` object attached to your `function` object. For example:

In a file called `funcs.py`:

```
external_object = "external object"
def f():
    print(external_object)
    nested = "nested"
    def g():
        print(nested)
    return g
```

Now, in an interpreter session:

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

```
>>> import funcs
>>> funcs.f.__code__.co_names
('print', 'external_object')
>>>
```

Or if you want the local variables:

```
>>> funcs.f.__code__.co_cellvars
('nested',)
```

You can also access other things, like the free variables. Notice, `nested` is a free variable in the closure for `g`:

```
>>> g = funcs.f()
external object
>>> g.__code__.co_names
('print',)
>>> g.__code__.co_freevars
('nested',)
>>>
```

Read more about the available attributes [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#index-53). I'll note, it probably isn't a great idea to rely on this, since as warned in the docs,

> Their definitions may change with future versions of the interpreter,
>   but they are mentioned here for completeness.

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you so much! That's what I was looking for. from what I understand, __code__ shows you the code for compiled objects. Is there a way to run this in a method?

Comment: @Akshay what do you mean "run this in a method"?

Comment: Example:
def magic_function(func):
   print func.__code__.co_names

or is that poor practice

Comment: Sorry, mixing up java and python here :P. Silly question, just ignore it

Comment: @Akshay That is not a method, that is a *function*. Python != Java, you aren't forced to write everything in a class definition.  But it looks like it would work, did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

The code object of the function (found in the `__code__` attribute) contains several attributes that give the values and names used in the code object itself, e.g. `co_consts`, `co_names`, etc.